# Keep File on iOS Device after App Update

Tags: ios, updates

Is there any way to create a file, which will not be erased after iOS has updated the app?

Scenario: My app saves a text file to the device, and after updating the app, some users are reporting that the text file is not there. Is there any way to preserve the files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the file in document directory then I should be there unless in the new version you create another file with same name and replace the previous one.

Comment: I ended up saving it 2 ways: NSUserDefaults and saving it as a document. Was there any way that it could have saved, but not be saved in the documents directory?

Comment: Yeah. If the data you are storing is not that much or if your data is only username and password then you could save it to keychain. But keychain can only save string, and I've asked a question about keychain limit of data that I can store but there was no specific answer. The best response I got was "Don't store too much data in keychain". What type of data you are storing?

Comment: I am storing just text. Is there a limit to how much can be stored in the keychain? and do you know if NSUserDefaults has a limit?

Comment: I searched and didn't get a specific answer. :s
Keychain string can hold over 4.2 billion characters same as the max length of NSString. About userdefault someone answered this "As long as there's enough space on the iPhone/iPad, you can store NSUserDefault values. All those values is stored into a .plist file, and this file is very small, most of the time under 1 kb (unless you store a lot of data)."

Comment: So which is slower to write to? NSUserDefaults or the Keychain?

Comment: Both are same I think, but implementing userdefault is easier than keychain. But there are a lot of lib that make keychain access like userdefault. If you are storing username or pass use keychain.